# Strategy Tester - Stop Loss is triggering before to reach the value stated

Tags: metatrader5

I´m trying to code a simple program to perform a stop loss and take profit operation through MT´s Strategy Tester without success. I´m using the MT 5.0, build 2085, and tried all kind of codes from Internet, including the ones written based on the standard library CTrade, but it doesn´t work.

The behaviour I´m facing is that the MT is triggering the Buy Stop Loss before the current price to reach the SL threshold.

The code below was taken from the book "Expert Advidor 5 - Programming for Meta Trader", by Andrew r. Young, page 83:

```
int OnInit()
   double StopLossPorc=9.0;
   double StopLossPrice=0.0;
   double TakeProfitPorc=4.0;
   double TakeProfitPrice = 0.0;

   vPrecoAsk = SymbolInfoDouble(_Symbol,SYMBOL_ASK);
   TakeProfitPrice = vPrecoAsk+((TakeProfitPorc)/100*vPrecoAsk);
   StopLossPrice = vPrecoAsk-(StopLossPorc/100*vPrecoAsk);

   request.action = TRADE_ACTION_DEAL;
   request.type = ORDER_TYPE_BUY;
   request.symbol = _Symbol;
   request.volume = qtde_compra;
   request.type_filling = ORDER_FILLING_FOK;
   request.price = vPrecoAsk;
   request.sl = 0;
   request.tp = 0;
   request.deviation = 50;
   request.magic = 43;

   OrderSend(request,result);

   request.action = TRADE_ACTION_SLTP;
   request.symbol = _Symbol;
   request.sl = StopLossPrice;
   request.tp = TakeProfitPrice;
}
```

I´ve ommited the rest of the script just for a matter of simplicity.

As can be seen in the logs through the link below, the stop loss was set to $13.16 when the buy order was sent, but the sell was performed at $14.47 based on a trigger whose the price was higher than the SL. Notice that the Low price in the respective period was $14.45, quite higher than the SL set ($13.16).

How can I code it in a way the stop loss is performed only when the current price reaches the SL defined?

[Metatrader Logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uz0iE.png)